# Does the infinite double sum $ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{Fib(mn)}{Fib(m+2)^{2n}} $ converge, and if yes, to what?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCVPXxNQVIM) by Prof. Michael Penn, I was recently playing around with "geometric" summations involving the Fibonacci sequence, as in $$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{Fib(mn)}{a^n}, \forall a \; | \; \sqrt[m]{a} > \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},$$ for integers $ m $.

I already know that $$ \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{Fib(mn)}{2^{mn}} $$ converges, because $ Fib(x) < 2^x, \forall x \in N $, with its value $ (4.761...) $ being dependent on the Lambert series and q-digamma function. Also some playing around led me to $$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{Fib(mn)}{Fib(m+2)^n} = \dfrac{Fib(m+2)}{Fib(m)}, $$ obtained through Binet's formula, d'Ocagne's identity and Lucas numbers relations.

However I'm still troubled with finding the exact value of $$ \displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{Fib(mn)}{Fib(m+2)^{2n}} $$ So far I've only advanced in proving the convergence through Binet's formula expansion. Can anybody help?